# RSS Feed fetching incomplete description - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, rss

I am using [Swift Feed Parser](https://github.com/DigitalLeaves/SwiftFeedParser) for RSS feeds. Everything works fine except that I am unable to fetch the complete description. The description is under the `<content:encoded>` tag in my RSS feed. So how do I fetch that?

I am using this code given in their demo to fetch `<description>` tag:

```
if let subtitleLabel = cell.viewWithTag(3) as? UILabel {
     subtitleLabel.text = item.feedContentSnippet ?? item.feedContent?.stringByDecodingHTMLEntities() ?? ""
}
```

Please help. I am using Xcode 8 and Swift 3.

Comment: Are you sure the `[…]` is not coming directly from the RSS feed ? I mean the feed has the complete description ?

Comment: @BogdanFarca please check updated question. I need to access data under the <content:encoded> tag. I found out that the <description> tag itself had [...].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, let's try to suggest some hints on how to approach this:

- First, the [...] was coming from the RSS feed `<description>` itself and not from the parser, so this one is solved
- In order to extract instead the `<content:encoded>` tag from the feed you should I guess modify a little bit the feed parsing library, after quickly looking at it's source code, it doesn't seem to look for `<content:encoded>` anywhere
- Your best bet would be to modify the `FeedParser` class [here](https://github.com/DigitalLeaves/SwiftFeedParser/blob/master/FeedParser/FeedParser.swift), especially the function `parseEndOfAtomElement` or similar (they have different parsers for each RSS feed type they support)

Please tell us if it worked.

Comment: My rss feed type is .RSS2 in feedsDateFormat(). I cannot modify the class as I am new to rss feeds. Please could you provide any help on this.

Comment: It's not about RSS feeds it's about modifying a Swift method :-) You should find the place where the `<description>` tag is extracted and replace it with `<content:encoded>`.

Comment: Bogdan, can you help answer this question too https://github.com/DigitalLeaves/SwiftFeedParser/issues/10